# MinGW g++ creates no output in powershell

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, gcc, mingw

I've seen a little similar, two year old question like this, but no answer was found...

Under Windows 7 64bit, I've been trying to compile a simple "hello world" C++ source code with MinGW gcc version via Power Shell. Environment variable was added. From Power Shell I can access the compiler, for eg. `g++ --help` works well, but no executable or any other output is created when compiling.

This is in main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Tried with this:

```
g++ -o test.exe main.cpp
```

When I hit enter, the compilation is done seemingly, but no any response comes and my source code still sits alone in his folder.

[PS g++ no output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnhth.png)

If I take a mistake in the source file, the compiler recognizes it, and error message comes as normal.

I've removed link from here (only 2 links are allowed for me :( )

If I compile with -Wall, warning message also comes for a deliberate mistake.

So it seems to be okay at this point. Just to be sure i've searched the entire hdd for my test.exe, but it's nowhere...

Anyway I'm using Code Blocks for programming C++. So the mentioned MinGW gcc is installed alongside with Code Blocks. From Code Blocks it works well, without any problems.

Then I've installed MinGW independent from Code Blocks to C:\MinGW, taking care of not to use any spaces in directory names. MinGW v0.6.2-beta-20131004-1 is installed. Everything happened the way as mentioned before. Environment variable was updated of course, but still no executable is created or any response in Power Shell that would indicate the failure of the process.

Tried with both Power Shell and Power Shell (x86). Same happened.

Please help me with any ideas to le me know what I'm doing wrong.

UPLOAD:
As suggested by Jean-François Fabre, I've run the g++ command with option -v, the result is here: 
[run with option -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe0gL.png)

Comment: I think that g++ silently crashes, which explains that no executable is created. you could try `-v` option (verbose) to see what's going on.

Comment: Are you using the Powershell GUI?  It might be worth checking to see whether the console version exhibits the same behaviour or not.  (Open a cmd.exe window and run "powershell".)

Comment: All these things mentioned above happened in the console version.

I've refreshed the original post with the result of the -v option running.

Comment: Note that if you omit `-o test.exe` like in your screenshot, g++ produces `a.exe` as the output executable.

Comment: You're using Powershell. That's wrong. I have never encountered a piece of software so openly designed to foil its alleged purpose: a command interpreter that is unable to run programs in general, because it can't pass general arguments, with scripting disabled by default, horrible syntax that has almost no general features, all special cases, use of unreadable colors in the console, no technical documentation, just vague descriptive task-specific things, and so on. Simply, don't use it, unless you're doing .NET programming.

Comment: Hypothesis: Powershell doesn't like the word "test". Use a different name. But better, ditch Powershell.

Comment: Yes, I know if no output name is defined it will be "a" by default. The problem still exist witout output name given. No any a.exe is created. However now I've discovered that

Comment: powershell may has a general problem. I've compiled my "hello world" on an other win7 machine with exactly the same method, and even the compiled a.exe can not be run. I typed .\a command in the folder of a.exe and nothing happened just when trying to compile with g++.

Comment: By the way, I'm new to powershell. Do you have a suggestion for any better console platform under windows?

Answer (score 2):

As one of the deleted answers says, this problem doesn't happen when `g++` resides in current directory. Moreover, I've found that it also doesn't happen when it's accessible via the `PATH` environment variable. I don't know the reason for this (might be related to search paths for shared libraries or for auxiliary executables), but the following fixed it for me on Msys2:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/mingw64/bin/
```

After the above I do get useful stderr output from `g++`, and generally the compiler works as expected.

Comment: I don't have an answer, just observation..
I had same issue with "helloworld" cpp app compiled with mingw64 and executed in Powershell - no cout output. In regular 'Windows command prompt' and MinGW64 Terminal it worked.

I've checked the PATH and it was setup correctly ("C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\" was there).

Then I ran PowerShell as administrator and executed hellowrold app again and the output is there. From this time I have no issue.